# Basis of Mathematics

Tags: axioms, peano-axioms

I was reading up on Goedel's Theorems and was wondering  what exactly is the basis of Mathematics today and is the discussion around an axiomatic system settled? I know that there are several attempts like the Peano Axioms or the Zermelo-Fränkel Set Theory but I am not sure which one is the most "used" today. I hope I am not posting this in the wrong subforum.

Comment: ZFC is the most common.

Comment: Most working mathematicians pay no attention to the question of axiomatic systems for Mathematics.